# Magento 2 content overview not loading

Tags: magento2

I am new to Magento, and i just installed a clean build in CPanel.

My content overview in backend won't load.

Pages, blocks and widgets overview is not showing any results, even though i just saved a page, and cleared cache.

As you see here, no pages are getting fetched. (Pages have been added, and can be viewed in the frontend, if going to the URL i added to the page.) 
[image]
No errors in console neither.

What can the problem be?

Comment: Hi there Anders. Please provide us code snippets, detailed reproduction steps, screen shots, anything at all that can help. Until you provide more detail I'll go ahead and put this on hold.

Comment: Updated. Should be clear what the problem is. :)

Comment: check  server logs. it's possibe that something wrong with layout files.

Comment: Not sure what to look for, but nothing seems odd. It's a complete new clean install 2.0.2

Comment: Okay. Is fixed it self. I have no idea how, so i can't set an answer. Just opened the site this morning, and it worked. Not sure if the cronjobs did the job, because i already ran the cronjob manually.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was with the browser.
It worked in Firefox - and did not work in Chrome.